# How to integrate facebook login in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an app in which I want to **integrate Facebook login** to facilitate user to login with his/her Facebook account and retrieve user details like **name, mobile, etc..**. How can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/SocialLoginIntegrationAndroid

Comment: what had you done till now

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
```

in manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
```

in Strings.xml file

```
<string name="fb_app_id">1723658174519153</string>

fbConnectHelper.connect();
```

[FbConnectHelper](https://github.com/ErNaveen/SocialLoginIntegrationAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/binarywalllabs/socialintegration/helpers/FbConnectHelper.java)

[SocialLoginIntegrationAndroid](https://github.com/ErNaveen/SocialLoginIntegrationAndroid)